# Understanding bootstrap, config.php, application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I´m still beginner with Zend Framework. If I read different articles I wonder which are the differences between the three configuration files, bootstrap.php, config.php and application.ini.

I only use the application.ini, my bootstrap so far ist empty (of course it is called in my index.php), at the moment I don´t have a config.php. If I would have started with different tutorials it could have been different, I guess. Is there a tutorial for better understanding when to use which possibility? Is the using only feeling based or can somebody explain the advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `bootstrap` extends `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` and gives you the opportunity to add in any functionality you might need for the application during its startup phase (e.g. registering plugins etc).

`config.php` and `application.ini` are essentially the same thing, just different formats. You could also do `config.xml` if you prefer. `application.ini` is the default when creating a new ZendFramework 1 application using the `zf` command line tool.

`config.php` is essentially just a flat PHP file that returns an array that `Zend_Config` then uses. `application.ini` allows for the same thing but with the `INI` config format. It's consumed with `Zend_Config_Ini`.

Comment: ok, if I understand it right, you have either config.* or application.ini?

Comment: @pia-sophie pretty much. `application.ini` is my favourite.